# How to add element to sub/nested document with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The below code is a 4 year old example I found in a Youtube video. When I run it, I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Can someone figure out what the new syntax is?

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const commentSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  username: String,
});

const postSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  username: String,
  comments: [commentSchema],
});

const PostModel = mongoose.model('post_coll', postSchema);
const CommentModel = mongoose.model('comment_coll', commentSchema);

const aPost = new PostModel({
  text: 'one',
  username: 'two',
});

aPost.comment.push({
  text: 'one',
  username: 'two',
});

aPost.save((err, res) => {});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong it's done like this, let me know if this works, thanks.

```
aPost.updateOne({
  username: "two"
}, {
  $push: {
    comments: ["Some text", "some username"]
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't get an error, but nothing is inserted either.